# Por que este código não está gerando a média corretamente?

Tags: c, algoritmo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



float media(int n, float* v){

int i;
float s;

s = 0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
s += v[i];
return s/n;}

}

float variancia(int n, float* v, float m){

int i;
float s;

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
s += (v[i]-m)*(v[i]-m);
return s/n;}

}

int main(){


float v[10];
float med, var;
int i;

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
printf("Digite um numero:\n");
scanf("%f", &v[i]);

}

med = media(10, v);
var = variancia(10, v, med);

printf("Media = %f Variancia = %f \n", med, var);



return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O principal problema é que o `return` está dentro do laço, então ele faz o cálculo no primeiro passo e já sai da função em seguida. Retirando o `return` do `loop` ele só é executado no final quando todo ele foi executado.

Isto ocorre porque o código está muito desorganizado. Fica difícil entender o que está acontecendo. Aproveitei para melhorar isto também.

Não verifiquei se os cálculos estão corretos.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float media(int n, float* v) {
    float s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) s += v[i];
    return s / n;
}

float variancia(int n, float* v, float m) {
    float s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) s += (v[i] - m) * (v[i] - m);
    return s / n;
}

int main() {
    float v[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Digite um numero:\n");
        scanf("%f", &v[i]);
    }
    float med = media(10, v);
    float var = variancia(10, v, med);
    printf("Media = %f Variancia = %f \n", med, var);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/psy5Ly). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rqkomery-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Loop/Exit.c).

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta colocar o `return` fora das chaves do `for`, se não ele sai da função na primeira interação.

Se só isso não funcionar, tenta manipular `v` como ponteiro, e não como vetor. Assim:

```
S  += v + (i * sizeof(float));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!